# Ajax callback appending desired url to existing url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a ajax call back to a Drupal 7. The problem I am encountering is that the url I want to use to make the callback is appended to the current page the user is viewing. I am not sure why this is happening and am wondering if some can point out my error for me. Here is the javascript code I am using to make the call:

```
(function($)  {
  function todaysHours(context)  {
    var callbackFunction = window.location.host +'/' + Drupal.settings.library_hours.callbackFunction,
    content = $("#todays-hours").find(".block");

    nIntervId = setInterval(checkTime, 300000);
    function checkTime() {

        request = $.ajax({
            url: callbackFunction,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "GET"
        });

        request.done(function( result ) {
           content.text(result[0].data);
        })
    }
  }

  Drupal.behaviors.library_hours = {
    attach: function(context)  {
        todaysHours(context);
    }
  }
})(jQuery);
```

The url I expect to use is http://mydomain.com/ajax/get-time but what is actually being used in the ajax call is http://mydomain.com/current-page/mydomain.com/ajax/get-time even though the callbackfunction variable is set to mydomain.com/ajax/get-time.

Why is this happening and how do I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're missing the protocol. (`http://`, or, `window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host`) Or, better yet, simply remove `window.location.host +`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem:
Protocol is not defined in the url

Solution: 
update the following part in the code

```
(function($)  {
  function todaysHours(context)  {
  var callbackFunction = '//'+window.location.host +'/' + Drupal.settings.library_hours.callbackFunction,
  // rest code
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: That was it. I knew I was having a brain-fart moment. Thanks for pointing that out.